# Texbox to number binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I'm using a [WatermarkTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WatermarkTextBox&referringTitle=Home) and I'm binding it's value to a View Model integer property. The thing is: I need that if there's no value set then the [WatermarkTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WatermarkTextBox&referringTitle=Home) must show the watermark but, given that it's bind to an integer when there's no value set (like when the view is shown) then it shows 0.

I can't use `OneWayToSource` cause I need two way binding. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a converter. If the value is 0, the converter returns an empty string, which makes the watermark visible. If it's not 0, it returns the string representation of the number.

```
public class Int32ToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int v = (int)value;
        if (v == 0)
            return string.Empty;
        return v.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string s = (string)value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return 0;
        return int.Parse(s);
    }
}
```

Another option is to change the property to `int?` (`Nullable<int>`), and set its initial value to null.

Comment: Tomas your solution works but now when the input is not a number then it throws an exception (I know is the int.Parse(s) within the ConvertBack but, the thing is. As it comes, when the conversion fails the textbox border turns red (I suppose it its something related to conversion error notification) the thing is. Is it possible to notify the sender -in this case the textbox- that the conversion failed or, how can I manage the case when the user input an string instead a number?

Thanks

Comment: Forget it, just wrote a Regex. Thanks

public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture ) {
            string s = (string)value;
            if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( s ) )
                return 0;
            s = Regex.Replace( s, "[^0-9]", "" );
            return int.Parse( s );
        }